# Getting the yearly income percentage for the top(100) Male and Female Seperated in 2 columns using AdventureWorksDW2016 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the percentage of top(100) yearly income(YearlyIncome) from dbo.DimCustomer, and I want 2 columns '%M' and '%F' that shows the percentage of yearly income for Males and Females

Here's my code:

```
Select Top(100) 
  Case dbo.DimCustomer.Gender 
    When 'M' Then (Count(dbo.DimCustomer.Gender)*100)/sum(YearlyIncome)
  End as '%M',
  Case dbo.DimCustomer.Gender 
    When 'F' Then (Count(dbo.DimCustomer.Gender)*100)/sum(YearlyIncome)
  End as '%F'
From 
  dbo.DimCustomer
Group By 
  Gender
```

This is the result I am getting. Am I doing it right?

And can I show them without `Null` - just 2 columns side by side with 1 row which is the percentage?

Comment: Sample data and expected results make a good addition to a SQL question, ideally a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Averages involves dividing by the number of entries, not multiplying.

Comment: Top 100 ordered by what? you have no `ORDER BY`. Also `TOP 100` will be calculated after grouping so only works if you have 100 genders, I don't think we're quite there yet

Comment: @Charlieface i dont think i need it cuz i should have just 2 columns and 1 row right ?

Comment: @shawnt00 ok i will edit this one and thank you i missed this one

Comment: Well if you want the top 100 *of* something, you need to define: what you want the top of, and what top actually means, what's the top and what's the bottom. Otherwise you get arbitrary rows

Comment: @Charlieface ok so in my case Order By YearlyIncome

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data, please paste in as either Markdown Tables or `CREATE` `INSERT` statements. So you want the top 100 of *each* gender, or the top 100 of the whole table? Is the percentage only of that gender, or of the whole set?

Comment: @Charlieface i want to get the Top(100) of both genders and then calculate the YearlyIcome percentage of Males and then Females

Comment: @Charlieface Yes but out of the whole set of 100 rows

Comment: Am I misunderstanding: 1. you want top 100 males *and* top 100 females? Or 2. you want the top 100 of the whole set whether male or female? 1. or 2?

Comment: @Charlieface i want 2

Comment: OK have modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get them into the same row you can use conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  MalePct   = SUM(CASE WHEN c.Gender = 'M' THEN c.YearlyIncome END) * 100.0 / SUM(c.YearlyIncome),
  FemalePct = SUM(CASE WHEN c.Gender = 'F' THEN c.YearlyIncome END) * 100.0 / SUM(c.YearlyIncome)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (100)
      c.YearlyIncome,
      c.Gender
    FROM dbo.DimCustomer c
    ORDER BY c.YearlyIncome DESC
) c;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your helping so far but i am getting error "invalid column name 'Gender'" on second and third line after case when

Comment: Change inner query to include `Gender`

Comment: @Kirito Should be fixed now. Lack of sample data means it's difficult to test

Comment: thats excatly what i wanted thank you very much